# Rails 4: Friendly_id gem finding users by username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails 4 app where I am trying to create permalinks with friendly_id gem based upon a users "username". The error I receive when I try to create a permalink based upon a users username is `"undefined method username="` and it points to my User_controller
 Here is my code so far.

**Users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end


  def show
    @user.username = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

   def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user #edit_user_path(current_user)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

 def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followed_users.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :username, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

    def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
      end
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def career_finder

    end
end
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend FriendlyId

  friendly_id :username, use: [:slugged, :finders]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To lookup the user by friendly_id:

```
def show
  @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

This is covered in the [readme for friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)